# Wine 6 cannot start the game when render = vulkan

Tags: wine, vulkan

Wine 6 introduces experimental Vulkan renderer. However when I try to execute a game having that renderer set I get the following error:

```
0024:err:winediag:wined3d_dll_init Using the Vulkan renderer.
0024:err:winediag:wined3d_spirv_shader_backend_init_vk Wine was built without libvkd3d-shader support.
```

I installed wine from `deb https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/ focal main`. The same is reproducible for stable and devel builds.

Is there a way to get workable wine build having vulkan renderer supported?